# Unable to perform XML external entity validation using SaxParser while unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, saxparser, owasp

Hi I tried the below code for validating whether an input XML is having external entity references, but the code is not throwing any exceptions even when i provide an XML input which contains External entities

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(<XML content here as byte array>);
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader reader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
Source xmlSource = new SAXSource(reader, new InputSource(bais));
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller =
JAXBContext.newInstance(XXXX.class).createUnmarshaller();
return (XXXX) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlSource);
```

Tired directly setting the features in  XMLReader as well

```
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader reader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
    reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
    reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
    reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    Source xmlSource = new SAXSource(reader, new InputSource(bais));


Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller =
    JAXBContext.newInstance(XXXX.class).createUnmarshaller();

return (XXXX) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlSource);
```

both approaches are not working and no exceptions are thrown

Please let me know if any thing is wrong with this. I am trying to implement https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Unmarshaller

Answer (score 0):

This is the code we use for disabling external entity processing in ZAP:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
```

https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/develop/src/org/zaproxy/zap/utils/XmlUtils.java